# Identical print layout for multiple maps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mapping

I am new to QGIS and can’t find the answer to my question anywhere online. Once I create a print layout which I am happy with, is there any way to use the same layout for other maps as well? I.e. use the same placement of legend, scale, north arrow, grid etc. and the same fonts etc. for a new map without having to set it all from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

You can save it in a project or in your profile templates. See more [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/overview_composer.html#the-layout-manager).

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to duplicate layout.

If you have a layout you want to reuse within **the same project**, you can use the duplicate button.
[image]

It will create a new layout exactly copy of your current layout. Then you can change the title, legend item, map themes...